# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable - Web Crawler

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm very new to stack overflow and even newer yet to coding. I made this web crawler from a bit of this and that I've found over a multitude of web searches. My intention is to take a keyword input and search it on google crawling through each page and returning email addresses into a csv file. It worked just yesterday now i'm getting this error 503 error. Can anyone please show me how to overcome this? Here is my code.

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import scrapy
import time

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from googlesearch import search



def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    time.sleep(2)
    return urls



class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'email'

    def parse(self, response):

        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link) 

    def parse_link(self, response):

        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return

        html_text = str(response.text)
        mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)

        dic = {'email': mail_list, 'link': str(response.url)}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)
        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False)

def ask_user(question):
    response = input(question + ' y/n' + '\n')
    if response == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def create_file(path):
    response = False
    if os.path.exists(path):
        response = ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
        if response == False: return 

    with open(path, 'wb') as file: 
        file.close()

def get_info(tag, n, language, path, reject=[]):

    create_file(path)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['email', 'link'], index=[0])
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    print('Collecting Google urls...')
    google_urls = get_urls(tag, n, language)

    print('Searching for emails...')
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    process.crawl(MailSpider, start_urls=google_urls, path=path, reject=reject)
    process.start()

    print('Cleaning emails...')
    df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
    df.columns = ['email', 'link']
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='email')
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df.to_csv(path, mode='w', header=True)

    return df

bad_words = ['facebook', 'instagram', 'youtube', 'twitter', 'wiki']
df = get_info(input('What keywords would you like to collect emails for?:'), int(input('How many Websites would you like to crawl?')), 'pt', input('Enter a name for csv file:')+'.csv', reject=bad_words)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if this makes a difference but I logged into my other google account and it started working again.